# building a type of pixel sorting in glsl

Tags: sorting, opengl, video, glsl, max-msp-jitter

I'm working on emulating in glsl an effect I've seen used pretty widely (example in image). I am new to glsl, but have a decent amount of experience in max msp and jitter, so that is where I am trying to implement it (syntax should be similar enough though, but it's glsl version 2.1).

Currently, I am taking in one texture, then feeding the output back in as the second texture. Using a luma threshold, I am selecting pixels to be sorted, but from here, I can't figure out how to continue. I assume that I need to:

1. Take the color value from the initial, luma selected pixel.
2. Apply that color to subsequent pixel along a certain axis.

And now I can't figure out how to continue. I'll include the code that I do have, which obviously just has nothing after the luma threshold stuff. Any advice or resources would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
        uniform sampler2DRect tex0;
        uniform sampler2DRect tex1;

        varying vec2 texcoord0;
        varying vec2 texcoord1;

        uniform float thresh;
        const vec4 lumcoeff = vec4(0.299,0.587,0.114,0.0);

        void main()
        {
            vec4 input0 = texture2DRect(tex0, texcoord0);
            vec4 input1 = texture2DRect(tex1, texcoord1);

            float luma = dot(input0,lumcoeff);

            if(luma > thresh){
                gl_FragColor 
            }else{ 
                gl_FragColor = input0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do but my bet is you need to cast a ray in specific direction to integrate the colors from source texture until treshold is reach. Very similar to this [2D raycasting light effect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34708022/2521214) just use constant ray direction (as some uniform) instead of the light source direction (fragment-mouse position) and change the color combining equation ...

Answer (score 3):

I actually made the original image you posted up above. Sorting on the GPU can be a complicated task because we can't easily make comparisons the same was that a CPU can.

I'd take a look at this nvidia paper on a [bitonic merge sort](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter46.html). [I implemented it in glsl here](https://adamferriss.com/merge/) if you'd like to take a look, though I think chrome auto play killed it so you may need to try in FF or Safari.

There's also a few examples on [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdcGWf) if you search around. I think [this one might be pretty close to what you're hoping for](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4lBBRz)

Good luck!