# GLSL Smooth border shader

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl, shader

I'm looking for a specific shader or an idea for another approach to get the desired result.

A picture shows the desired result (left-side input, right-side output):
[image]

I already experimented with modifying a simple vignette shader:

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler2D;

const float outerRadius = .65, innerRadius = .4, intensity = .6;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_sampler2D, v_texCoord0) * v_color;

    vec2 relativePosition = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution - .5;
    float len = length(relativePosition);
    float vignette = smoothstep(outerRadius, innerRadius, len);
    color.rgb = mix(color.rgb, color.rgb * vignette, intensity);

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

I think it's more confusing than helpful when I show you my modified code. I tried to imitate the same concept as of the vignette shader: Used the bounding box of the island, transforming x,y,width,height in screenCoords and get the relative position of fragCoords to island's center (normal vignette would use the screen resolution instead the island 'resolution'). Then I wanted to invert the vignette effect (inside dark, outside fade out)

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I think whole approach should be changed.

Second idea is to place a dark light in all islands on my map. (with Box2DLights)
But this might be a little expensive?

Any other ideas?

Comment: How is the input image created / rendered in the first place?

Comment: The input is created with procedural generation ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation ). Each vertex is stored in a PolygonSprite ( from libgdx ) and is rendered by a suitable SpriteBatch (PolygonSpriteBatch). The green platforms get separated redered (these are normal sprites). Just the filling of such an island is a polygonsprite.

Comment: add precomputed attribute distance from the edge and use that as blur/darkening strength. Otherwise you need to cast rays and detect this distance in shader which is slow (similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/34708022/2521214) ...

Comment: You can try to use erosion filter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology). You render object to black-white texture. Then apply erosion filter. You can use result mask to apply darkness to result frame. It needs additional render pass, it can be little slowly.

Comment: thanks Spektre and Unick for your suggestions. I will evaluate both :)