# How to use OpenGL to achieve the effect of light curve

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I want to achieve a glowing line effect

[image]

I tried to use a texture map, but it's hard to avoid the redraw that caused the transparency overlay. The input data is input from the mouse in real time. The result is as shown

[image]

We are currently studying the use of Gaussian blurring. 
Ask if the seniors can use Gaussian blurring to achieve an effect or have other ideas.

Comment: yes you can use blurring for this .... render `for (i=0;i<n;i++) { render_line();  blur(); }` but much faster is to convert your polyline to thick quad strip  and use 1D semitransparent texture for it with alpha blending...

Comment: @Spektre A thick quad strip is currently used, but a 2D texture with a width of 1px is used

Comment: that is the same as 1D so where is the problem? or you want to go with bluring? (that will be slow !!!)

Comment: @Yangli also check this [How to implement 2D raycasting light effect in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34708022/2521214) out.  You could use similar techniques inside shader ... encode your polylines into texture and inside shader compute the fragment distance to your polylines and add lightness to color ... the rendering will consist of single QUAD covering your screen. Here [Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) example of passing geometry this way ...